# On click of checkAll checkbox, push its objects in another array object and remove from existing array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Functionality I want to implement is that when I click on "select All" checkbox, I want to push the selected item in new array and delete from current one.

Tried with splice function, but not able to delete all items from the first table.

`enter code here`Here is the [sample plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/PjuLWhu65zLtejSeW6jK?p=preview) I have created, So when I click on "select All" from first table, all its items should get pushed in "New Table" and at the same time removed from "First table(named Old table)

Comment: Do add your code in OP as well...

Comment: What is meant by OP? This is sample plnkr I have created, I need to implement the same functionality in my project

Comment: This seems to be `for-loop` and `DOM-manipulation` question.. What have you tried ?

Comment: ___OP___ ==> _Original Post_

Comment: Yes. Can you help me with some other alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use `angular.copy` to make an copy of the object

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("SecondCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.merged = [];
  $scope.data = [{
    "name": "ABC",
    "selected": false
  }, {
    "name": "HJK",
    "selected": false
  }, {
    "name": "PQR",
    "selected": false
  }, {
    "name": "LMN",
    "selected": false
  }];

  $scope.selectall = function(checkAll) {
    if (checkAll) {
      $scope.merged = angular.copy($scope.data);
      $scope.data.length = 0;
    } else {
      $scope.data = angular.copy($scope.merged);
      $scope.merged.length = 0;
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
  <div>
    <h1>Old Table</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectall(checkAll)" ng-model="checkAll">Select All</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected">
          </td>

          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div>
    <h2>New Table</h2>
    <table ng-show="merged">
      <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in merged">
          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/fqon3cvh/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Rayon :-)

Comment: In pune as a AngularJSJavascript Developer, a newbie

Answer (score 1):

This will clear your array and push all entries in $scope.merged

```
$scope.pushlist = function(data){
    for(var item of data){
        $scope.merged.push({"name":item.name});
    }
    data.length=0
};
```